# How can I make .htaccess to ignore rules if folder exists?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can I make `.htaccess` to ignore rules if folder exists?

Rules:

```
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)$ index.php?ht=$1&hht=$2
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/$ index.php?ht=$1&hht=$2
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)$ index.php?ht=$1&hht=$2
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/$ index.php?ht=$1&hht=$2
```

For example:
if I go: `http://my_domain.com/admin` it redirects to `index.php` on original document root, not the `/admin/index.php`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing these lines on top of your code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```